# Order of commands when migrating to Git LFS and tracking files

Tags: git, git-lfs

I want to use LFS for an existing Git repository and track `*.foo` files, converting the files in history too. I guess I can do this:

```
git lfs track "*.foo"
# changed `.gitattributes` and all `.foo` files
commit -a -m "Started tracking foo files."
git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.foo"
```

Should I track the files before importing the repository, as I do above, or should I do that afterwards? Does it matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In trying it both ways, it appears that importing a repository will turn on LFS tracking automatically, so there is no need to use `git lfs track` separately.

```
git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.foo"
```

In fact if you turn on tracking first, then you will have an extra commit where the file types are added to `.gitattributes`. It turns out that `git lfs migrate import` will actually add a `.gitattributes` with the correct tracking information *as the first commit in the history*. If you don't have a `.gitattributes` file, one will be added *in the past*.

Similarly if you don't have a `.gitattributes` (let's say you converted the Git repository from a Subversion repository, for example), then if you first add your own `.gitattributes` to the repository and commit it before doing `git lfs track`, this will result in a version of `.gitattributes` in the history that does *not* have LFS tracking turned on. If you do decide to add `.gitattributes` manually, you should perform `git lfs track…` before committing the file so that it will have tracking turned on in all the commits in which it appears.

So the best approach seems to be:

1. Perform `git lfs migrate…` before you do anything else.
2. Update the `.gitattributes` file that Git added with extra file types (if you didn't have a `.gitattributes` file already).

In summary, `git lfs migrate import …` seems to include `git lfs track …` functionality; there seems no need to call the latter separately, either before or after.